# Query global secondary index in dynamoDb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to check with a query if there are any items with that value on my table based on the global secondary  index. I'm new to dynamo and I'm using java with the AWS SDK v2. I'm not sure if to do the query I have to just query it with the name of the index and then use both the partition key and sorting key.

```
public Integer checkIfExists(String serialNumber) {
        String tableName = System.getenv("TABLE_NAME");
        String partitionKeyName="GSI4PK";
        String partitionKeyVal="GSI4SK";
        String partitionAlias="#a";
        // Set up an alias for the partition key name in case it's a reserved word
        HashMap<String, String> attrNameAlias = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attrNameAlias.put(partitionAlias, partitionKeyName);
        // Set up mapping of the partition name with the value
        HashMap<String, AttributeValue> attrValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        attrValues.put(":val1", AttributeValue.builder().s(serialNumber).build());
        QueryRequest queryReq = QueryRequest.builder().tableName(tableName)
                .keyConditionExpression(partitionKeyName + " = :val1").
                expressionAttributeValues(attrValues).indexName("CertificateDirect").build();
        try {
            QueryResponse response = dynamoDbClient.query(queryReq);
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            System.out.println(response.count());
            return response.count();
        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

I have seen also that there is a value named partitionAlias which I'm not sure what it does

Comment: As you are new to DynamoDB and Java V2, see this example. It will help you. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/EnhancedScanRecordsWithExpression.java

Comment: yes thank you, just that the example is for a scan not for a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do a query using java with the AWS SDK v2

```
private Map<String, AttributeValue> getDynamoQuery(String partitionKeyName, String sortingKeyName,
            String partitionKey, String sortingKey, String tableName, String indexName) {
        HashMap<String, AttributeValue> attrValues = new HashMap<>();
        attrValues.put(":val1", AttributeValue.builder().s(partitionKey).build());
        attrValues.put(":val2", AttributeValue.builder().s(sortingKey).build());
        QueryRequest queryReq = QueryRequest.builder().tableName(tableName).indexName(indexName)
                .keyConditionExpression(partitionKeyName + " = :val1 and " + sortingKeyName + " = :val2")
                .expressionAttributeValues(attrValues).build();
        QueryResponse response = dynamoDbClient.query(queryReq);
        return response.items().get(0);
    }
```